# Cron job syntax for Quartz Jobs

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I want a cron job running within my Quartz job scheduler running at 00:01 every day.

What is the cron expression for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
0 1 0 1/1 * ? *
```

Explanation:

The first value (0 in this case) is the seconds, the second value (1) is the minutes, the third value is the hours (0 for 12 am), the fourth value is the day of the month (1/1 means everyday), the fifth value is the month (* means all months), the sixth value is the day of the week (? means no specific value), the seventh value is the year (again * means every year).

Comment: could you please explain why 1/1?

Comment: cronmaker says for every hour, it should be this: 0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *. Could you maybe also explain why daily is 1/1 and every hour is 0/1?

Comment: I'm not 100% but it would be dependant on the preceding values you also use. So I'm thinking 1/1 means once every day then something like 1/5 would mean once every 5 days. Putting a 0 fìrst (like 0/1) must be the way to set hourly stuff so 0/1 is once every hour, 0/5 would be once every 5 hours. I'm no expert on Cron expressions they're tricky things!

Answer (score 1):

```
0 1 0 ? * * *
```

see also [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com)